# Поиск коммита по содержимому

Tags: git, git-log

Хочу найти свой коммит, diff которого содержит изменения с числом `333` в некоторой строке - оно было удалено либо добавлено в некую строку в данном коммите. Возможно известна папка (но не файл), в которой это было сделано.

С автором коммита вроде проблем нет:

```
git log --author=Qwertiy
```

а вот как сюда приписать поиск по содержимому изменённых строк?

Comment: для этого служит опция `-p`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ответы - в ответы

Comment: Вообще-то ещё есть -S

Comment: И это всё написано в документации, блин

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Достаточно простое решение (которое не даст информацию о хеше коммита):

```bsh
git log -p | grep <pattern>
```

В `git` есть [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep), с ним решение будет выглядеть лучше:

```bsh
git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)
```

[Оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/3422245)

Comment: Только в файл вывод скинул и там поискал. А то у меня винда.